# Retrieved a String from ServletRequest by using getParameter("somename"). How can I turn it back into the XML that it is?

Tags: java, xml

I'm parsing a ServletRequest object(well, a HttpServletRequest really)
Have 2 parameters there, one of them I know to have a value which is an XML file.

How can I retrieve that XML as Doc or byte[] or similar, rather than String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can convert `String` to `byte[]` easily enough using its `getBytes()` function.
- If you want a Doc, you'll have to parse it. To do that, you can get a `DocumentBuilder` from `DocumentBuilderFactory` and let that `parse()` a `ByteArrayOutputStream` wrapped around that byte array.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string which contains XML, you can parse that into a Document by parsing from a StringReader which wraps the String. Don't convert the String to bytes unless you can deal with the potential encoding issues.

builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(theString))

Comment: More strongly, don't convert the String to bytes so the parser has to convert from bytes back to a character stream.  That's two unnecessary transcoding steps that may not agree on the character set and subtly corrupt the data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to refactor into your solution as soon as possible